# Default value for database field using Sequelize migrations

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

It's the third day I'm trying to accomplish this simple task using sequelize but I'm having a really hard time doing it.
All I want is to create a table with two fields:

- id (type: int)
- publicId (type: uuid)

The id field is the primary key, auto increments etc..
The publicId field should be of the type UUID and it's values should be ***automatically*** generated, by the "defaultValue" attribute.
I've tried all sorts of combinations in the creation of the model or the migration file when creating the table. Also it is not a problem with sync because each time I remove my db container, spawn a new one and migrate all again.

I'm using sequelize-cli v5.5.1, but I tried v6.2 as well.

The code:
(migration file)

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('orders', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      publicId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('orders');
  }
};
```

model file:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const order = sequelize.define('order', {
  }, {});

  order.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return order;
};
```

The migration is ran successfully, but only the 'id' field is set with default values. The publicId field just has the non-null constraint, and the default values are not created.
I've tried many other approaches, like setting a function as defaultValue that returns a uuid, already tried `Sequelize.fn('uuid_generate_v4')`, and others.. defaultValues field just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the new columns to the model file as well, and designating the attribute options.

As an aside -- I always turn off strict mode because it's given me strange issues.

Comment: Nop, same problem :/

Comment: Which sql dialect is your database in?

Comment: Postgres.. Do you think it's the problem?

Comment: Possibly. Try setting the type attribute on publicId to Sequelize.UUIDV4, and still reflecting the createTable in the model file.

Comment: It didn't work :/ When I run the migrations there's an error:  `type "uuidv4" does not exist`

Comment: Ah my fault, the type attribute needs to only be Sequelize.UUID like you originally had it since uuidv4 is a standard and not a type.